# CreateFileMapping() returns null

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to follow this tutorial on MSDN: [Creating Named Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551.aspx).

Unfortunately, I get `NULL` from `CreateFileMapping()`. The file `shmfile.txt` exists on my file system, so I thought no problems should occur, the mapping would be created, and the file would take its role as my shared memory object.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
...
#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("C:\\Users\\joe\\shmfolder\\shmfile.txt"); 
int main(){
    HANDLE hMapFile; // filehandle
LPCTSTR pBuf; 
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
    NULL,                    // default security
    PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
    0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
    BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
    szName);                 // name of mapping object

if (hMapFile == NULL)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"), GetLastError());
    return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You should first `CreateFile()` to get a handle to your file and then call `CreateFileMapping()` with the file handle as the first parameter. And make sure you are calling the right version of function (`CreateFileMappingA()` for ANSI string or `CreateFileMappingW()` for wide string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, you're telling `CreateFileMapping` to create the mapping in the page file, then use the name of your existing file as the name of the file mapping.

The name you give for a file mapping object can have `local\` or `global\` as a prefix, but can't contain any other back-slashes.

If you want to map your pre-existing file as a shared memory region, you'd do something on this general order:

```
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("C:\\Users\\joe\\shmfolder\\shmfile.txt"); 
TCHAR szMapName[]=TEXT("SharedFile"); 

HANDLE file = CreateFile(szName, ...);
HANDLE mapping = CreateFileMapping(file, ..., szMapName);
```